# Next (2007) Missing Scene

Tags: alternate-version, next

I recently had a rewatch<sup>1</sup> of Next (2007) on Netflix, and had a feeling one of the scenes I remembered was missing.

The scene I recall was in the end of the film. It depicted Nicolas Cage's character using his powers to cold call Julianne Moore's character. He used the landline telephone in the motel to brute force all thinkable numbers until he heard her voice.

Were there alternate versions made of this film? Am I remembering the scene correctly, and if so, what version was I watching? Why was it missing from the Netflix release?

If it helps, I first saw the film on a rental DVD in Europe.

<sup><sub><sup>1</sup> Strictly to be able to give it a proper rating.</sub></sup>

Comment: I don't recall the scene and I can't find any reference to any deleted scenes on a DVD.

Comment: I don't remember it either, and frankly it sounds ridiculous; he'd potentially have to dial millions of numbers for hundreds of years just to call her, which would probably drive him insane. Plus I'm pretty sure he already knows her number at that point anyway.

Comment: @Walt that raises another good question: [when did he get her number?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61271/41610). And although you raise a reasonable point, a million seconds takes about 11 days. Multiply it by about 5 (the time it takes to dial one of them) and you're still in under a year. And we don't know how he experiences any of it (nor if he narrows it down somehow). And should we really be dismissing something as "ridiculous" when the movie literally is about a man who can see and change the future (and didn't have the foresight to get a flattering hair-cut)?

Comment: Yeah, I was way off, it'll probably just take a few years (I skipped a step). But my (rough) estimate was based on the fact that he'd have to dial, *wait for the person at the other end to pick up*, recognize the voice and hang up. And sometimes people don't pick up, so it'll take way more than 5 seconds on average. And we know this happens in real time (for *him*) because, well, he won't *imagine* calling all those people, it would really happen. But I agree that the entire thing is almost as ridiculous; I only know this movie well because I like its Rifftrax track. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be remembering this incorrectly.

I've looked at a couple of online versions on [**Youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFDRU2kqito) (1:27:30) and neither of them showing Cage "bruteforcing" the number.

Indeed, he uses a **cellphone** to make the call to Moore not a landline.

[image]

[image]